# 48bit and 28bit ATA commands with ioctl

Tags: c, ioctl

During sending ATA commands I found several classifications. For example, first one - we can divide the commands to Data-In, Data-Out and Non-Data commands. Another classification can be that there are 48bit commands and 28bit comands. First ones are for the disks, which are larger that 120Gb.

The question is: do I need to set up some values that the disk will know that it get the 48bit command or not? For example, if I send SCSI command with ATA through SATL or ATA PASS THROUGH command through the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the research it was found that every controller has its own specificities depending on the driver. That is why implementation of ATA PASS THROUGH commands are so difficult work.

Through reading the Linux driver and checking what structures are sent with ioctl it is possible to figure out if it is 28 or 48 bit command.

Moreover, it is also quite important to check how new is the software, because 48-bit Logical Block Addressing (LBA) was introduced in 2006 in ATA-6 standard. Most probably nowadays all the controllers supports 48-bit command set, but still you should check if the controller supports it.

So, the answer to this question strongly depends on the using controller.

Comment: NCITS 361-2002 was released, well, in 2002. And even if we are talking about "released products" I can already find mentions of the thing in the 2002's ICH3 datasheet (and I'm not sure [how much](https://www.ixbt.com/storage/ide-till-ata100.html) of ATAPI-6 couldn't already be inside the even earlier Ultra ATA/100). By 2006 you already had the first drafts of ATA-8 flying around.